# Performance of Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have a question about performance of Forge Viewer, and i think its big problem when the end users approach this technology. In Debug enviroment its so smoothly, i dont have any problems, model doesnt reload all the times. However, when i deploy application, its a different story. Take a look link below you can see how it lag, like the model reload all the times when ever i do something.

I use Firebase for my frontend and Azure for my backend. What is the problem or i must config something?

https://youtu.be/c4QbAknZNRY

Appreciate any comments.

Paxton.

Comment: Viewer rendering depends on the end user's web browser and the object quantity inside the view. It looks like that the two views are not the same one, and the second one has more objects to render for the viewer. Could you try test the same model on the both envs?

Comment: You may also test with turning off the progressive rendering inside viewer configuration panel, but it takes more resources to handle rendering.

Comment: yes, i already did that but i think the main problem is the browser. my local project, deployed project even viewer website of Autodesk have the same situation. My 
normal browser dont have any extension but browser come from debug enviroment works well. You can see the video below, notice the deployed project in debug enviroment, it works well but still reload all the time.
[link](https://youtu.be/P7shVbCOQWY)

Comment: It seems that you opened two viewer apps in different URLs, could you try to keep only one viewer app opened during tests? All opened viewer apps are shared the same graphic card and its memory.